# Sending emails to multiple adresses using MvcMailer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, mvcmailer

I have an `emails` variable that contains a list of e-mail addresses of users in a role. The list is not comma-separated. Here's the code that I have at the moment:

```
    public virtual MvcMailMessage AdminNotification()
    {
        var userRoles = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin");
        var users = new List<MembershipUser>();
        var emails = new List<String>();
        foreach (var UserName in userRoles)
        {
            var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName, false);
            users.Add(user);
            emails.Add(user.Email);
        }

        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "AdminNotification";
            x.ViewName = "AdminNotification";
            emails.ForEach(user => x.To.Add(user.Email));
        });
    }
```

I get an error stating `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Email'...`

What should I use instead of `x.To.Add(user.Email)`?

**Update #1**

I'm able to send out e-mails to the intended recipients, but the message body is blank. The message body has been constructed in a View. It was working before I used the code in the answer below, how can I get it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd rewrite it:

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage AdminNotification()
{
    string[] userRoles = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin");

    IEnumerable<string> emails =
        userRoles.Select(userName => Membership.GetUser(userName, false))
                 .Select(user => user.Email);

    var message = new MvcMailMessage {Subject = "AdminNotification", ViewName = "AdminNotification"};

    foreach (string email in emails)
    {
        message.To.Add(email);
    }
    return message;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The message body is blank. The View I've created for the body does not appear in the e-mail. How can I fix that?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I've found a solution and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Update #1:**

Made some minor tweaks to the code and now it's working as expected, just had to move some things around. Here's the part that was tweaked:

```
var message = new MvcMailMessage {Subject = "AdminNotification"};

foreach (string email in emails)
{
    message.To.Add(email);
    PopulateBody(message, ViewName = "AdminNotification");
}
return message;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send emails using the original code (using lambda expressions), although there seems to be a usage issue with it. In the code the lines:

```
return Populate(x =>
    {
        x.Subject = "AdminNotification";
        x.ViewName = "AdminNotification";
        emails.ForEach(user => x.To.Add(user.Email));
    });
```

reuse the emails list, which is a list of strings, so instead of referencing a user in the .ForEach, an email string should be the parameter (left hand side), thus the solution would be:

```
return Populate(x =>
    {
        x.Subject = "AdminNotification";
        x.ViewName = "AdminNotification";
        emails.ForEach(email => x.To.Add(email));
    });
```

It might not be of any help, just wanted to clarify that.. :)